# How can real $d$ orbitals be computed from complex orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals, spherical-harmonics

I recently completed MIT's 8.04 quantum mechanics course on edX and have been writing python code to compute hydrogen-like electron orbitals, basically just for fun.  My program computes the eigenstates based on $n$, $l$, and $m$ and uses the mayavi 3D graphics package to plot it.

My question concerns computing the $s$, $p$, $d$, and $f$ orbitals in real bases by superposition of the (complex) eigenstates. I found how to do this for $p_x$ and $p_y$ and it works as intended.

$$
p_z = p_0 \\
p_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(p_1 + p_{-1} \right) \\
p_y = \frac{1}{i\sqrt{2}} \left( p_1 - p_{-1} \right)
$$

So how do you do something analogous to compute $d_{z^2}$, $d_{xz}$, $d_{yz}$, $d_{xy}$, and $d_{x^2-y^2}$? From looking at some tables and observing patterns, I'm guessing that I need to do:

$$
d_{z^2} = d_0 \\
d_{xz} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(d_1 + d_{-1} \right) \\
d_{yz} = \frac{1}{i\sqrt{2}} \left( d_1 - d_{-1} \right)\\
d_{xy} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(d_2 + d_{-2} \right) \\
d_{x^2 - y^2} = \frac{1}{i\sqrt{2}} \left( d_2 - d_{-2} \right)
$$

and similarly for the $f$ orbitals with $m = \pm 1, 2, 3$.

Thanks for any clarification on this. Nothing important is on the line, but I hope to understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the appropriate combinations of [spherical harmonics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics).  Indeed the real functions are sums and differences $Y_{\ell}^m$ and $Y_{\ell}^{-m}$.  The real forms are given [a little later](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#Real_spherical_harmonics) in the same wiki page.